# Как реализовать число скачиваний в Django

Tags: python, django

Есть сайт про программы разных категорий. Есть два главных шаблона: 1. Где находятся все софты; 2. Собственно страница данного софта.

В моделях софта написал поле downloads, собственно число скачиваний:

```
class Soft(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Фото софта')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, verbose_name='Название софта')
    published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Категория')
    downloads = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Скачивания')
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='files/', verbose_name='Файл софта')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Софт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Софты'
        ordering = ['-published']
```

Не понимаю как это сделать. Подумал, может на js, написал простой скрипт, но и он неправильно работает, просто в js не очень шарю.

Может помочь кто-нибудь, заранее всем спасибо. Если что-то еще нужно будет обязательно скину(фотку, код и т.д.)

Answer (score 1):

В `view`, которое обрабатывает запросы на скачивание, нужно добавить увеличение счетчика скачиваний:

```
soft = Soft.objects.filter(id=<уникальный идентификатор из запроса>)
soft.update(downloads=F('downloads') + 1)
```

Обратите внимание, что в `filter` нужно передать предикат, который однозначно идентифицирует `soft`. Из модели в описании неочевидно, как это происходит. Тут я для примера использовал поле `id`, которого сейчас в модели нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Есть кнопка <Скачать>, а как сделать взаимосвязь этой кнопки и поля id?

Comment: Как у вас сейчас идентифицируется файл для скачивания? Как представление, которое обрабатывает запрос знает, какой именно файл пользователь хочет скачать? Вполне возможно, что это совершенно другой вопрос, который требует дополнительной информации о том, как у вас реализовано. В комментариях эти подробности не опишешь, да и не место им тут. Задайте новый вопрос и подробно опишите. Либо добавьте  в вопрос кнопкой"править" информацию о том, как реализована идентификация.

Comment: Я понял о чем вы, просто в вебе еще новичок. вот код контроллера данного софта:https://pastebin.com/zrqJtTKM

Comment: Вот контроллер главной страницы: https://pastebin.com/QhsayeKW. И вот как я пытаюсь вывести число в главной странице: https://pastebin.com/nKSUNYnM